# Angular -> ng-repeat filtered array variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below I will put link to my example in Plunker to show you my problem.
In `ng-repeat` I have used `array(filtrowane)` to store data from filter result, also I have added ng-change on input for showing the value of `filtrowane.length` in console. Variable filtrowane is defined in controller, and after typing something It`s showing different values in console and in the view, can you tell me why?

PS. run your web browser console and you will see the difference.

[example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6rQGAl8pGbLgALXRlO63?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change value, first ng-change is called, then $digest starts which will update `filtrowane`.
If you use such notations:

```
item in filtrowane = (tablica | filter:search)
```

do not use `filtrowane` in controller. Html should be view, so you should not declare any variables there, which you use in model (js).

Look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/QAHlbuZqWX4szglvMP87?p=preview
This code does same as yours, but filtering is done in javascript. A bit more complicated, but things are more clear. (it is also better for big arrays)

Comment: Thanks for answer, earlier I did exactly this same as you and It`s working fine. I was just wondering If there is any possibility to make this outside of controller. So, I will stick to this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-blur` instead of `ng-change`

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" ng-blur="sprawdzFiltr()">
```

This is due to the `ng-change` is probably executed before the filter is applied, so the old value will be taken.

Comment: Thanks for answer, It`s working but I need something like solution above.